# Is It possible, do not mine ERC based token on the time of deployment in Ethereum test or private Blockchain

Tags: mining, private-blockchain, erc-20, rinkeby, erc-223

I am new to ethereum block-chain.I have created **ERC** based token (**smart contract**).I successfully deploy it on ethereum local private block-chain.

When I will deploy smart contract token on **rinkeby test network or main network**. So, two question in my mind:-

1.**How mining will be done?**

2.**And Is It possible I do not mine my  ERC based token when I deployed it on **ethereum main network** or rinkeby test network**??

It might be a silly question but here i want to understand this concept more deeply.

Please help to clear my above query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [ERC20 Token Standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md) you get to define the `totalSupply` as a part of the contract creation. So these tokens do not need to be mined, they will simply all exist as soon as you create the contract.

Comment: Thanks Shawn,But in ERC223 token,need mining or not??

Comment: The [ERC223](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223) standard, which builds on ERC20, does not change the way tokens are created, so it will not need to be mined.

Comment: And I want to deploy decentralise application on ethereum main netowk or test network(rinkeby) in this case,need to mining or not??

Comment: And Please tell me how mining will be done??

Comment: The point of using Ethereum is that as a dApp developer, you do not have to worry about things like mining, or setting up a network, or anything like that. The Ethereum platform is flexible enough such that you can build your applications on top of it, and then take advantage of all the existing infrastructure to just work.